# jQuery select closest tr with specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of items inside a table. I have decided to change the table structure a bit so that things look more organized, and added some more `<tr>`'s in.
What happened is that my jQuery code doesn't work well anymore.

I have that piece of code:

```
$(':input:not(.ajax-confirmed)').each(function(m,r){
    var $row = $(r).closest('tr');
    $row.remove();
});
```

I would simply like to select the closest `<tr>` and signify it with an additional parameter, I thought maybe a class, so that I know what kind of `<tr>` I am removing.

How can I select the closest tr with a specific class name?

Comment: Show your relevant HTML structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, depending on your HTML structure:

```
$(':input:not(.ajax-confirmed)').each(function(m,r){
    var $row = $(r).closest('tr.className');
    $row.remove();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the documentation, you will find this example:

```
$('li.item-a').closest('ul', listItemII)
```

.css('background-color', 'red');

The second parameter coult be a class name. So in your example, just add something like this:

```
var $row = $(r).closest('tr', 'some class name');
```

Comment: The second parameter is a *context* to search in (used as a container of how far to go), it can't be a class name (well it can in some cases, but it's very inefficient).  Instead you'd want `.closest('tr.class')`

Answer (score 0):

"I would simply like to select the closest  "

```
.closest('tr')
```

or

```
.closest('.myclass')
```